# Will an Emagic Logic Control work properly with Logic 8 or 9?

Tags: logic-pro

The Mackie website is hopeless when it comes to determining compatibility. Will the original, Emagic-branded, Logic Control unit work with Logic 8 or 9? Will you get full functionality out of it (channel names appearing and time code showing up properly, for example)?

Edit: It was originally released with Logic 5 -- back when Emagic wasn't owned by Apple, that's why I'm wondering if compatibility has been maintained as Logic progressed through its versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work pretty well with 9.  I can see the time code, record enable tracks, undo, click track, transport, scroll around banks, view effects, see track names, so yeah...working.  Sometimes the logic control confuses me and I'm not really sure I totally understand all the view modes - but I get by.

Comment: No problem - how much are they going for these days?